# Debezium is not pushing data to kafka from postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1, debezium, change-data-capture

I am trying to do CDC using debezium on postgresql. I ran the following docker images

```
> ZOOKEEPER

docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 
quay.io/debezium/zookeeper:2.2


> KAFKA

docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper quay.io/debezium/kafka:2.2

> KAFKA-CONNECT

docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link kafka:kafka  quay.io/debezium/connect:2.2

> KAFKA-UI (GUI for kafka)

 docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED=true provectuslabs/kafka-ui

> POSTGRESQL

docker run --name postgresql -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123 -d debezium/postgres
```

I used below configuration to generate the postgresql connect

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json"
-H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ 
-d '{
  "name": "psql-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "192.168.29.219",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.dbname": "demo",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.include.list": "demo",
    "table.include.list": "public.company",
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "topic.prefix": "psqlserver",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory.demo"
  }
}'
```

it created a connector on checking url
`http://localhost:8083/connectors`

but on `kafka-connect` it is stopped at

````
 Postgres|psqlserver|streaming  Requested thread factory for connector PostgresConnector, id = psqlserver named = keep-alive   [io.debezium.util.Threads]
Postgres|psqlserver|streaming  Creating thread debezium-postgresconnector-psqlserver-keep-alive   [io.debezium.util.Threads]
Postgres|psqlserver|streaming  Searching for WAL resume position   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource]```

I am adding image too fur details of console `[![enter code here][1]][1]`

I


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgBGp.png
````